# How to approach this problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The shape of the graph of a flying bird has the shape of $y = \frac{1}{100}\cos(\frac{1}{2}x + 3) + \frac{1}{4}$, the displacement in the $x$-direction as a function of time: $x(t) = 200t - 100t^2$.
Determine the velocity $v(t)$ of the bird in the vertical direction.

I know the first derivative of position is the velocity. So, is this as simple as just taking the derivative of $x(t)$? I'm not so sure what to do with the formula for $y$...

So then I thought of the following: since $y$ can be considered as a function of horizontal displacement, then we get a new formula: $$y = \frac{1}{100}\cos(\frac{1}{2}(200t - 100t^2) + 3) + \frac{1}{4}$$ which I can then differentiate using the chain rule.

Is this approach correct? If not, how should I approach this?

I'd like to come up with the actual answer myself, so I'm just looking for an approach.

Comment: `is this as simple as just taking the derivative of x(t)` That would give you the velocity in the horizontal direction, but the problem asks for the "*velocity v(t) of the bird in the vertical direction*". `... which I can then differentiate using the chain rule` That's correct, $v(t)=\Big(y\big(x(t)\big)\Big)'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approach is correct, and $v_y(t) = \frac{dy}{dt} $.

or from the beginning, $v_y(t) = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} $